# Antonyms of `assignee`

Tags: word-choice

How to name the people who have been assigned to do some task? I want to give some meaningful name to my variable, but I can't find appropriate word for it. So here is my scenario, there is an admin in app, who can assign roles to users, I need to call these users.

Here is an example:

```
public function assign(Role $role, Admin $assignee, array $THAT_WORD_WHICH_I_NEED = [])
{

}
```

Comment: It is the "*antonyms day*" today!!

Comment: A person who is assigned to do a task **is** an assignee. It's **also** someone to whom something is assigned.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Really?? GoogleTranslator lied me? I'll remove this silly question then :)

Comment: If I assign a task to you, I'm the assingner, you're the assignee. @AndrewLeach is right.

Comment: Just remember _trainer_ and _trainee_. Who trains, and who is trained?

Comment: @xurshid29 Google Translate in notorious for lying **to** people. I wouldn't trust it for a second...Searching in a [reputable dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assignee) is safer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Assign* is a slightly odd verb.

Someone who assigns is an *assigner*. So far, so good: that much is regular.

Someone who is assigned by the assigner is an *assignee*. That's regular, too: it follows the same pattern as *trainer* and *trainee*.

It's **also** the word for the person **to whom something is assigned:**

> - The assigner assigns the assignee to perform a particular role.
> - The assigner assigns the role to a particular assignee.

Note that in those two sentences, the direct object **and** the indirect object of *assign* are both *assignee.* In **practice,** it's the assignee who gets to fulfill the role in both sentences, but the grammar is different.

For your particular case, it appears that you need your "Admin" to be *assigner* and the role's recipient to be *assignee.*